# Estendendo layout

Tags: laravel-blade

Tenho 2 arquivos:

**app.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

**cliente.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   <form></form>
   <table></table>
   <div></div>
@endsection
```

Gostaria de saber se há como no arquivo *cliente.blade.php* estender outro arquivo?

Exemplo do que eu gostaria de fazer:

**cliente.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   @section('formulario') // Aqui uso section ou yield
   <table></table>
   <div></div>
@endsection
```

**formulario.blade.php**

```
@extends('cliente')

@section('formulario')
    <form></form>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substitua em **cliente.blade.php**

```
@section('formulario')
```

**por**

```
 @yield('formulario')
```

a formulario.blade pode manter como está e ai o conteudo da section('formulario') dela entra na yield('formulario') da pagina extendida

**exemplos que usei nos meus testes (Meu laravel é 5.8) :**

analises.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('user','Willian')

<!-- inicio do conteúdo -->
@section('content')

<textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="">@yield('descricao')</textarea>

@endsection
```

analisesdesc.blade.php:

```
@extends('analises.analises')

@section('descricao')
    Teste
@endsection
```

rota:

```
Route::get('/analises' , 'AnalisesController@index')
```

metodo index no AnalisesController:

```
public function index(){
   return view('analises.analisesdesc');
}
```

resultado foi o campo descrição (textarea) com a palavra teste

Comment: Já tentei isso e não tive sucesso. Mas da pra fazer isso?

Comment: dá... acabei de testar, porém sua rota tem que apontar pra formuario.blade

Comment: Poderia me mostrar um exemplo da rota?

Comment: editei a resposta ai man. qlq coisa da um toque

Comment: Obrigado amigo, esclareceu minha dúvida

Comment: Não há de que parceiro